# Looping through JSON file. If there is no data - do fallback

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I was hoping that someone could help with with this loop that I have which goes through all the json objects and then takes specific data from that object.

I keep running into the same problem -

I am looking for the url of a thumbnail for instance. The .each function will loop through the JSON and take the required data. But if there is one object that doesnt have the thumbnail property then I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'full' of undefined"...

This is understandable because there is nothing there. So I want to make a check that makes sure that it has the property first, if it does, it takes the data, if it doesn't then it goes somewhere else in the json file to get the data.

I have included a small snippet of my ajax call and Jquery loop. I have indicated the Problem area with a comment and I have linked the JSON file for you to take a look at/use.

Any help would be appreciated!

CODE -

```js
$("#search-btn").click(function (e) {
    
            var userText = $.trim($('#searchArea').val());
            $('.full-post-img').css('display', 'none');
            $('.full-post-text').css('display', 'none');
            $('#op').attr('checked', false);
    
            $.getJSON('http://www.capetownetc.com/api/get_search_results/?search=' + userText, {
                    srsearch: userText
                    , action: "query"
                    , list: "search"
                    , format: "json",
                },
                      
                function (data) {
                
                    if(userText.length === 0){
                        $("body").append("<p class='results'>Please enter a keyword</p>");
                         $('#sLoad').css('opacity', '0');
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#swipe").empty();
                        
                        $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
//                          $('#sLoad').css('opacity', '0');
                            
                            //EXCERPT
                            var ex = item.excerpt;
                            var maxLength = 100;
                            ex = ex.substr(0, maxLength);
                            
                            //THUMBNAIL
                            //***PROBLEM AREA***
                            var imgThumb1 = item.thumbnail_images.full.url;
                            //So on certain keywords that are being searched, the JSON object might not have the "thumnail_image" property, so it's undefined and breaks the rest of my code, so then it must go somehwere else and get it. (Probably done with a if/else statement"
                            
                            
                            //CATEGORY
                            var cat = (item && item.categories && item.categories[0] && item.categories[0].title) || userText;
                            
                            if(cat.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                                console.log('Is valid');
                            }

                            
                            console.log(cat);
                            
                            $("#swipe").append('<div class="p1 full-post-text"><a class="p1 link-click" id="post2" target="_blank"></a><div class="p1 text-post-img"><span class="p1 card-img1" id="p1Img" style="background-image:url(' + imgThumb1 + ');"></span><a class="p1 post-cat">' + cat + '</a> </div><div class="p1 full-text-info"><h2 class="p1 text-heading" id="p1Heading">' + item.title + '</h2>' + ex + '</div></div>');
                            $('p.results').css('display', 'none');
                    }); 
                    }
                    //SEARCH SUCCESS
                    $('#sLoad').css('opacity', '0');
                    $('#results').css('display', 'inline-block');
                    $('#search-img').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#iSlider').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#searchBR').css('display', 'block');
                });
});
```

[JSON Data file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=96736933096373522572)

Answer (score 0):

you should check `if (typeof item.thumbnail_images !== "undefined" && item.thumbnail_images != null) { //do magic here } else { //handle undefined or null cases }`